# NSObject has no subscript members

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having an issue with trying to retrieve data from firebase. I keep getting an error which says NSObject has no subscript members when trying to append? Currently firebase is holding a Question, an array of different answers and a correct answer.

```
class QuestionList
{
//properties
public static var Username: String = ""
private static var quiz = [Question]()

static func getDummyQuestions()->[Question]
{
    //create some dummy data for the model
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: UInt!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference() //reference

    refHandle = ref.child("Questions").child("Q1").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot)in
        let dataDict = snapshot.value as? NSObject

        //let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        //let quest = value?["Question"] as! String
        //let Answers = value?["Answers"] as! String
        //let Correct = value?["Correct"] as! String

        //quiz.append(Question(q: quest, a:[Answers], c: Correct))

        quiz.append(Question(q: dataDict["Question"], a: dataDict["Answers"], c: dataDict["Correct"]))


        //quiz.append(Question(q: "hello", a: ["short long", "short char", "short float", "short int"], c: 2 ))
        //quiz.append(Question(q: "bye", a: ["short short", "short int", "short float", "short int"], c: 2 ))


      print (dataDict)
    })
    return quiz
}
```

}

```
class Question
{
var quest:String
var answers:[String]
var correct:Int

init(q: String, a:[String], c:Int)
{
    quest = q
    answers = a
    correct = c
}

func isCorrectQuestion(itemSelected: String)->Bool {
    if (itemSelected == answers[correct]) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

}
//}

Answer (score 0):

Let cast `snapshot` to a dictionary: `let dataDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]`

```
refHandle = ref.child("Questions").child("Q1").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot)in
    if let dataDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

        if let quest = dataDict["Question"] as? String,
            let Answers = dataDict["Answers"] as? [String],
            let Correct = dataDict["Correct"] as? Int {
            quiz.append(Question(q: quest, a: Answers, c: Correct))
        }
    }

    print (dataDict)
})
```

Comment: I put this in my code however I am getting this: "initialiser for conditional binding must have Optional type, not string

Comment: At this line `let Correct = dataDict["Correct"] as! String`, right? I just updated.

Comment: Now the appending has an error cannot convert value of type String to expected argument type [string]

Comment: still the same issue?

Comment: but now it says cannot convert value of type String to type int

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't test your code. But I think it's okay now! Please check

Comment: seems to work now but now I am having issues with the code on my view controller which contains the picker view and loads the questions from the Question class

Comment: Let ask another question, me and other people will help you solve it!

Comment: okay, let me read. If my answer solved this question, please accept it.

Comment: cool I upvoted the post please try and fix my issue if you can. Thanks